# RecyclerView load only one item

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Here RecyclerView loads only one item however the loops works prefect but with RecyclerView loads only one item and not load all items
.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

GetJson.kt

```
 class GetJson : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    var arrayList = ArrayList<JsonModel>()
    private var requestQueue : RequestQueue? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_json)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2)

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)


        val getButton : Button = findViewById(R.id.ShowButtonJson)
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        getButton.setOnClickListener {

         getFromServer()

        }

    }


    fun getFromServer(){

        val url = "http://..../testapp/getjson.php"
        val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null, {
          response -> try {
              val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("names")
            for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()){
                val name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                val firstname = name.getString("firstname")
                val middlename = name.getString("middlename")
                val lastname = name.getString("lastname")
                arrayList.add(JsonModel(firstname,middlename,lastname))

            }
            val namesAdapter = jsonAdapter(arrayList)
            recyclerView.adapter = namesAdapter
            namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
          } catch (e: JSONException){
              e.printStackTrace()
          }
        }, { response -> response.printStackTrace()
            
        })

        requestQueue?.add(request)
    }
}
```

jsonAdapter.kt

```
class jsonAdapter(val data : List<JsonModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<jsonAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    class ViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val firstnameText : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.firstnameView)
        val middlenameText : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.middleNameView)
        val lastnameText : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.lastNameView)


    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): jsonAdapter.ViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.jsonlist,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: jsonAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val namesModel =  data[position]

        holder.firstnameText.text = namesModel.firstname
        holder.middlenameText.text = namesModel.middlename
        holder.lastnameText.text = namesModel.lastname

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return data.size
    }
}
```

Comment: you sure there is only one item visible ? try to scroll might possible your Item layout is height is `match_parent`.

Comment: @ADM ok it works, but how to update recyclerview wihout adding same items as more without update currently items ?